# Using jQuery .load() returns a slightly different result than is actually in the page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Firstly, I'm using jQuery UI for skinning my buttons. I have a form that has a button. This form consists of a varying amount of checkboxes. If I have a checkbox go away, one of the button's methods is that on success of the checkbox removal, it `.load()`'s the new set of checkboxes without page refresh.

Here's the code:

```
$('#zoneRemove').live('click',function() {
        $.post('php/zoneNotifUnsub.php', $('#zoneNotifUnsub').serialize(), function(){
            $('#zoneDiv').load('notifications.php #zoneDiv');
         });
    });
```

It works great. The only problem is that when `#zoneDiv` reloads, it seems to return a different result, as my button is not skinned (the button is inside the div, placing it outside makes the entire thing not work). This typically is a symptom of a JS syntax error (as any error in my script causes button skinning to fail; this is a semi-useful bug/feature for debugging). However, I clearly do not change any JS code. The only thing that would change is the output of some PHP that is contained in `#zoneDiv`.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your button is being dynamically altered by JQuery UI. Just run `.button()` again on the elements inside that div (you can change `.button` to whatever function you need):

```
    $('#zoneDiv').load('notifications.php #zoneDiv', function(){$(this).find('.button').button();});
```

Whatever styling you do on that div on page load, you have to do it again.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing any type of styling with javascript when the page loads that you need to re-run whenever you reload the "#zoneDiv"?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're "skinning" buttons with code rather than markup (e.g., calling on jQuery UI's [`Button`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/) stuff), that's not going to apply automatically to new content. You'll need to re-run the code that you use to discover button instances and apply the skin to them.

Use the `load` callback to fire the code, e.g.:

```
$('#zoneRemove').live('click',function() {
    $.post('php/zoneNotifUnsub.php', $('#zoneNotifUnsub').serialize(), function(){
        $('#zoneDiv').load('notifications.php #zoneDiv', function() {
            // This is the callback; make all checkboxes in the content "buttons"
            $(this).find(":checkbox").button();
        });
    });
});
```

...or similar.

Answer (score 0):

are you using `$('mybutton').button()` to "skin" your buttons?   if so, you'll need to call it again, as the button you buttonized is gone, and .`button()` isn't live.

so try this:

```
$('#zoneDiv').load('notifications.php #zoneDiv', function(){
    $('mybutton').button();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be mentioned in your first paragraph: `I'm using jQuery UI for skinning my buttons`.  Whatever you're doing to skin your buttons also needs to be done to the newly loaded content.  i.e. if you are doing something like this on pageload:

```
$(function() {
  ...
  $('#zoneDiv button.my-button').button();
  ...
});
```

Then when the new `#zoneDiv` loads, all of the DOM elements that previously had the button function applied to them won't anymore.  So you'll have to do something like this, add a callback to the load() function.  This fires immediately after the new content gets stuck into the DOM:

```
$('#zoneDiv').load('notifications.php #zoneDiv', function(){
    $('#zoneDiv button.my-button').button();
});
```